# Iterating polygon creation in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have contour lines in a feature class. I covert the closed lines into polygons using the 'Feature to Polygon' tool. With this method I get concentric stripes, but I need the area of each area enclosed by a polygon.

For better understanding see the picture below. So I have the two contours - A and B. If if convert them by using the 'Feature to Polygon' tool on the whole featureclass I get the areas in option one: area enclosed by contour A, and a stripe between A and B. But I need option 2: the area enclosed by A and the area enclosed by B.

[image]

To do this I tried to run the 'Feature to Polygon' tool in model builder using on the output of a Feature Selection iterator, but I got an empty feature class.

[image]

What am I missing or the iterator tool is a wrong choice?

Comment: Please update your question to show a screen shot of how you set up the Feature to Polygon tool.

Comment: Your iterator should do it.. but probably not feature selection. You're wanting overlapping polygons aren't you? The feature to polygon tool will produce *planar* polygons when a new line is detected a new polygon is created, to create non-planar polygons you will need to polygonize each elevation (or feature, if 100% closed polylines are present) and then append the results to re-stack (or not, depending on what's needed). A bit more information about what you're trying to achieve as an end result would be helpful.

Comment: If you are after depth/area curve, your 'concentric' rings is what you need. Sorting them in descending or reverse order and computing accumulated area will produce the curve

Comment: I want to calculate rough volumes of the area covered with the contours. The area of each contour is needed to do the calculation in an other software.
I have tried to convert the polylines to 3d ones, but it was no help because making polygons of the 3D polylines resulted stripes just like using the 2D polylines. 
So I need overlapping polygons, they can be coplanar or parallel, the needed information is the contour (Z) value and the area of each polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your model is that, each time "Feature To Polygon" is executed, a new polygon feature class replaces the old one. To overcome this situation change the "output feature class" parameter of "Feature To Polygon" to :

**Output Feature Class:** `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\LineFC_%Value%`

`%Value%` is the objectid of the line feature which is changing into a polygon. Then do a Merge to merge all feature classes into a single one.

Comment: Farid Cher, thank You for your help!
The suggested method solved my problem.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that!